# Spark ALS predictAll returns empty

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have the following Python test code (the arguments to `ALS.train` are defined elsewhere):

```
 r1 = (2, 1)
 r2 = (3, 1)
 test = sc.parallelize([r1, r2]) 
 model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIter, lmbda)
 predictions = model.predictAll(test)

 print test.take(1)     
 print predictions.count()
 print predictions
```

Which works, because it has a count of 1 against the predictions variable and outputs:

```
[(2, 1)]
1
ParallelCollectionRDD[2691] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:423
```

However, when I try and use an `RDD` I created myself using the following code, it doesn't appear to work anymore:

```
model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIter, lmbda)
validation_data = validation.map(lambda xs: tuple(int(x) for x in xs))
predictions = model.predictAll(validation_data)

print validation_data.take(1)
print predictions.count()
print validation_data
```

Which outputs:

```
[(61, 3864)]
0
PythonRDD[4018] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43
```

As you can see, `predictAll`comes back empty when passed the mapped `RDD`. The values going in are both of the same format. The only noticeable difference that I can see is that the first example uses parallelize and produces a `ParallelCollectionRDD`whereas the second example just uses a map which produces a `PythonRDD`. Does `predictAll` only work if passed a certain type of `RDD`? If so, is it possible to convert between `RDD` types? I'm not sure how to get this working.

Comment: The first piece of code doesn't mean anything unfortunately. You have 2 entry ratings and 1 predictions output. That's two small to evaluate anything. As for the second part, it's unclear what are your ratings. How many of them they are ? What values are you using for your rank hyper parameter or how many iterations your training is supposed to perform , etc ? Your problem is unlikely to be solved with the provided information. Please read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The main point is that whilst the prediction in the first piece of code isn't going to be relevant, it still generates a prediction.The 2nd piece of code uses the same ranks and interations and doesn't generate a prediction. The validation data contains 8000 user,product id's. You can see a sample of what they look like in the 2nd output: [(61, 3864)]. Both use the same training data for the ALS model.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two basic conditions under which `MatrixFactorizationMode.predictAll` may return a RDD with lower number of items than the input:

- user is missing in the training set.
- product is missing in the training set.

You can easily reproduce this behavior and check that it is is not dependent on the way how RDD has been created. First lets use example data to build a model:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating

def parse(s):
    x, y, z  = s.split(",")
    return Rating(int(x), int(y), float(z))

ratings = (sc.textFile("data/mllib/als/test.data")
  .map(parse)
  .union(sc.parallelize([Rating(1, 5, 4.0)])))

model = ALS.train(ratings, 10, 10)
```

Next lets see which products and users are present in the training data:

```
set(ratings.map(lambda r: r.product).collect())
## {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

set(ratings.map(lambda r: r.user).collect())
## {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Now lets create test data and check predictions:

```
valid_test = sc.parallelize([(2, 5), (1, 4), (3, 5)])
valid_test
## ParallelCollectionRDD[434] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:423

model.predictAll(valid_test).count()
## 3
```

So far so good. Next lets map it using the same logic as in your code:

```
valid_test_ = valid_test.map(lambda xs: tuple(int(x) for x in xs))
valid_test_
## PythonRDD[497] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43

model.predictAll(valid_test_).count()
## 3
```

Still fine. Next lets create invalid data and repeat experiment:

```
invalid_test = sc.parallelize([
  (2, 6), # No product in the training data
  (6, 1)  # No user in the training data
])
invalid_test 
## ParallelCollectionRDD[500] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:423

model.predictAll(invalid_test).count()
## 0 

invalid_test_ = invalid_test.map(lambda xs: tuple(int(x) for x in xs))
model.predictAll(invalid_test_).count()
## 0
```

As expected there are no predictions for invalid input.

Finally you can confirm this is really the case by using ML model which is completely independent in training / prediction from Python code:

```
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS as MLALS

model_ml = MLALS(rank=10, maxIter=10).fit(
    ratings.toDF(["user", "item", "rating"])
)
model_ml.transform((valid_test + invalid_test).toDF(["user", "item"])).show()

## +----+----+----------+
## |user|item|prediction|
## +----+----+----------+
## |   6|   1|       NaN|
## |   1|   4| 1.0184212|
## |   2|   5| 4.0041084|
## |   3|   5|0.40498763|
## |   2|   6|       NaN|
## +----+----+----------+
```

As you can see no corresponding user / item in the training data means no prediction.

Comment: Good explanation. Led me to realize my training set was missing users.