# Serialize a custom transformer using python to be used within a Pyspark ML pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I found the same discussion in comments section of [Create a custom Transformer in PySpark ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331848/create-a-custom-transformer-in-pyspark-ml), but there is no clear answer. There is also an unresolved JIRA corresponding to that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17025.

Given that there is no option provided by Pyspark ML pipeline for saving a custom transformer written in python, what are the other options to get it done? How can I implement the _to_java method in my python class that returns a compatible java object?

Answer (score 40):

As of Spark 2.3.0 there's a **much**, **much** better way to do this.

Simply extend [`DefaultParamsWritable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.DefaultParamsWritable) and [`DefaultParamsReadable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.DefaultParamsReadable) and your class will automatically have `write` and `read` methods that will save your params and will be used by the `PipelineModel` serialization system.

The docs were not really clear, and I had to do a bit of source reading to understand this was the way that deserialization worked.

- [`PipelineModel.read`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/pipeline.html#PipelineModel.read) instantiates a `PipelineModelReader`
- `PipelineModelReader` loads metadata and checks if language is `'Python'`. If it's not, then the typical `JavaMLReader` is used (what most of these answers are designed for)
- Otherwise, `PipelineSharedReadWrite` is used, which calls [`DefaultParamsReader.loadParamsInstance`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/util.html#DefaultParamsReader.loadParamsInstance)

`loadParamsInstance` will find `class` from the saved metadata. It will instantiate that class and call `.load(path)` on it. You can extend `DefaultParamsReader` and get the [`DefaultParamsReader.load`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/util.html#DefaultParamsReader.load) method automatically. If you do have specialized deserialization logic you need to implement, I would look at that `load` method as a starting place.

On the opposite side:

- [`PipelineModel.write`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/pipeline.html#PipelineModel.write) will check if all stages are Java (implement `JavaMLWritable`). If so, the typical `JavaMLWriter` is used (what most of these answers are designed for)
- Otherwise, `PipelineWriter` is used, which checks that all stages implement `MLWritable` and calls `PipelineSharedReadWrite.saveImpl`
- `PipelineSharedReadWrite.saveImpl` will call `.write().save(path)` on each stage.

You can extend `DefaultParamsWriter` to get the [`DefaultParamsWritable.write`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/util.html#DefaultParamsWritable.write) method that saves metadata for your class and params in the right format. If you have custom serialization logic you need to implement, I would look at that and [`DefaultParamsWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/util.html#DefaultParamsWriter) as a starting point.

Ok, so finally, you have a pretty simple transformer that extends Params and all your parameters are stored in the typical Params fashion:

```
from pyspark import keyword_only
from pyspark.ml import Transformer
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasOutputCols, Param, Params
from pyspark.ml.util import DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit # for the dummy _transform

class SetValueTransformer(
    Transformer, HasOutputCols, DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable,
):
    value = Param(
        Params._dummy(),
        "value",
        "value to fill",
    )

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, outputCols=None, value=0.0):
        super(SetValueTransformer, self).__init__()
        self._setDefault(value=0.0)
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self._set(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, outputCols=None, value=0.0):
        """
        setParams(self, outputCols=None, value=0.0)
        Sets params for this SetValueTransformer.
        """
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)

    def setValue(self, value):
        """
        Sets the value of :py:attr:`value`.
        """
        return self._set(value=value)

    def getValue(self):
        """
        Gets the value of :py:attr:`value` or its default value.
        """
        return self.getOrDefault(self.value)

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        for col in self.getOutputCols():
            dataset = dataset.withColumn(col, lit(self.getValue()))
        return dataset
```

Now we can use it:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel

svt = SetValueTransformer(outputCols=["a", "b"], value=123.0)

p = Pipeline(stages=[svt])
df = sc.parallelize([(1, None), (2, 1.0), (3, 0.5)]).toDF(["key", "value"])
pm = p.fit(df)
pm.transform(df).show()
pm.write().overwrite().save('/tmp/example_pyspark_pipeline')
pm2 = PipelineModel.load('/tmp/example_pyspark_pipeline')
print('matches?', pm2.stages[0].extractParamMap() == pm.stages[0].extractParamMap())
pm2.transform(df).show()
```

Result:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|key|value|    a|    b|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1| null|123.0|123.0|
|  2|  1.0|123.0|123.0|
|  3|  0.5|123.0|123.0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+

matches? True
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|key|value|    a|    b|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1| null|123.0|123.0|
|  2|  1.0|123.0|123.0|
|  3|  0.5|123.0|123.0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: For those getting the error `AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'YourTransformerClass'` when doing [`Pipeline.load(filename)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.PipelineModel.load), try registering `YourTransformerClass` in the current `__main__` module by doing `m = __import__("__main__"); setattr(m, 'YourTransformerClass', YourTransformerClass)`. Have a look to the source of [`DefaultParamsReader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.DefaultParamsReader).

Comment: same error i am also getting . saving is done but while loading error is coming

Comment: question: why you put default values in the setParams() method?

Comment: @GeorgeC setParams is input to the keywords-only decorator; default values are required by the decorator, and the keyword arguments are saved as the attribute _input_kwargs

Comment: Is there a way to serialize the transformer in such a way that it's "self-contained" in the pipeline and you avoid having to load the class's code before loading the stored pipeline? I also get the error described by @mvillegas and it would be nice to not have to run the class code every time I load the stored pipeline.

Comment: @NicScozzaro not that I've found, but I would love to learn otherwise.

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure this is the best approach, but I too need the ability to save custom Estimators, Transformers and Models that I have created in Pyspark, and also to support their use in the Pipeline API with persistence.  Custom Pyspark Estimators, Transformers and Models may be created and used in the Pipeline API but cannot be saved.  This poses an issue in production when the model training takes longer than an event prediction cycle.

In general, Pyspark Estimators, Transformers and Models are just wrappers around the Java or Scala equivalents and the Pyspark wrappers just marshal the parameters to and from Java via py4j.  Any persisting of the model is then done on the Java side.  Because of this current structure, this limits Custom Pyspark Estimators, Transformers and Models to living only in the python world.

In a previous attempt, I was able to save a single Pyspark model by using Pickle/dill serialization.  This worked well, but still did not allow saving or loading back such from within the Pipeline API.  But, pointed to by another SO post I was directed to the OneVsRest classifier, and inspected the _to_java and _from_java methods.  They do all the heavy lifting on the Pyspark side.  After looking I thought, if one had a way to save the pickle dump to an already made and supported savable java object, then it should be possible to save a Custom Pyspark Estimator, Transformer and Model with the Pipeline API.

To that end, I found the StopWordsRemover to be the ideal object to hijack because it has an attribute, stopwords, that is a list of strings.  The dill.dumps method returns a pickled representation of the object as a string.  The plan was to turn the string into a list and then set the stopwords parameter of a StopWordsRemover to this list.  Though a list strings, I found that some of the characters would not marshal to the java object.  So the characters get converted to integers then the integers to strings.  This all works great for saving a single instance, and also when saving within in a Pipeline, because the Pipeline dutifully calls the _to_java method of my python class (we are still on the Pyspark side so this works).  But, coming back to Pyspark from java did not in the Pipeline API.

Because I am hiding my python object in a StopWordsRemover instance, the Pipeline, when coming back to Pyspark, does not know anything about my hidden class object, it knows only it has a StopWordsRemover instance.  Ideally, it would be great to subclass Pipeline and PipelineModel, but alas this brings us back to trying to serialize a Python object.  To combat this, I created a PysparkPipelineWrapper that takes a Pipeline or PipelineModel and just scans the stages, looking for a coded ID in the stopwords list (remember, this is just the pickled bytes of my python object) that tells it to unwraps the list to my instance and stores it back in the stage it came from.  Below is code that shows how this all works.

For any Custom Pyspark Estimator, Transformer and Model, just inherit from Identifiable, PysparkReaderWriter, MLReadable, MLWritable.  Then when loading a Pipeline and PipelineModel, pass such through PysparkPipelineWrapper.unwrap(pipeline).

This method does not address using the Pyspark code in Java or Scala, but at least we can save and load Custom Pyspark Estimators, Transformers and Models and work with Pipeline API.

```
import dill
from pyspark.ml import Transformer, Pipeline, PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.param import Param, Params
from pyspark.ml.util import Identifiable, MLReadable, MLWritable, JavaMLReader, JavaMLWriter
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover
from pyspark.ml.wrapper import JavaParams
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row

class PysparkObjId(object):
    """
    A class to specify constants used to idenify and setup python 
    Estimators, Transformers and Models so they can be serialized on there
    own and from within a Pipline or PipelineModel.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(PysparkObjId, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def _getPyObjId():
        return '4c1740b00d3c4ff6806a1402321572cb'

    @staticmethod
    def _getCarrierClass(javaName=False):
        return 'org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover' if javaName else StopWordsRemover

class PysparkPipelineWrapper(object):
    """
    A class to facilitate converting the stages of a Pipeline or PipelineModel
    that were saved from PysparkReaderWriter.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(PysparkPipelineWrapper, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def unwrap(pipeline):
        if not (isinstance(pipeline, Pipeline) or isinstance(pipeline, PipelineModel)):
            raise TypeError("Cannot recognize a pipeline of type %s." % type(pipeline))

        stages = pipeline.getStages() if isinstance(pipeline, Pipeline) else pipeline.stages
        for i, stage in enumerate(stages):
            if (isinstance(stage, Pipeline) or isinstance(stage, PipelineModel)):
                stages[i] = PysparkPipelineWrapper.unwrap(stage)
            if isinstance(stage, PysparkObjId._getCarrierClass()) and stage.getStopWords()[-1] == PysparkObjId._getPyObjId():
                swords = stage.getStopWords()[:-1] # strip the id
                lst = [chr(int(d)) for d in swords]
                dmp = ''.join(lst)
                py_obj = dill.loads(dmp)
                stages[i] = py_obj

        if isinstance(pipeline, Pipeline):
            pipeline.setStages(stages)
        else:
            pipeline.stages = stages
        return pipeline

class PysparkReaderWriter(object):
    """
    A mixin class so custom pyspark Estimators, Transformers and Models may
    support saving and loading directly or be saved within a Pipline or PipelineModel.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(PysparkReaderWriter, self).__init__()

    def write(self):
        """Returns an MLWriter instance for this ML instance."""
        return JavaMLWriter(self)

    @classmethod
    def read(cls):
        """Returns an MLReader instance for our clarrier class."""
        return JavaMLReader(PysparkObjId._getCarrierClass())

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, path):
        """Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of `read().load(path)`."""
        swr_java_obj = cls.read().load(path)
        return cls._from_java(swr_java_obj)

    @classmethod
    def _from_java(cls, java_obj):
        """
        Get the dumby the stopwords that are the characters of the dills dump plus our guid
        and convert, via dill, back to our python instance.
        """
        swords = java_obj.getStopWords()[:-1] # strip the id
        lst = [chr(int(d)) for d in swords] # convert from string integer list to bytes
        dmp = ''.join(lst)
        py_obj = dill.loads(dmp)
        return py_obj

    def _to_java(self):
        """
        Convert this instance to a dill dump, then to a list of strings with the unicode integer values of each character.
        Use this list as a set of dumby stopwords and store in a StopWordsRemover instance
        :return: Java object equivalent to this instance.
        """
        dmp = dill.dumps(self)
        pylist = [str(ord(d)) for d in dmp] # convert byes to string integer list
        pylist.append(PysparkObjId._getPyObjId()) # add our id so PysparkPipelineWrapper can id us.
        sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
        java_class = sc._gateway.jvm.java.lang.String
        java_array = sc._gateway.new_array(java_class, len(pylist))
        for i in xrange(len(pylist)):
            java_array[i] = pylist[i]
        _java_obj = JavaParams._new_java_obj(PysparkObjId._getCarrierClass(javaName=True), self.uid)
        _java_obj.setStopWords(java_array)
        return _java_obj

class HasFake(Params):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HasFake, self).__init__()
        self.fake = Param(self, "fake", "fake param")

    def getFake(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.fake)

class MockTransformer(Transformer, HasFake, Identifiable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MockTransformer, self).__init__()
        self.dataset_count = 0

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        self.dataset_count = dataset.count()
        return dataset

class MyTransformer(MockTransformer, Identifiable, PysparkReaderWriter, MLReadable, MLWritable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTransformer, self).__init__()

def make_a_dataframe(sc):
    df = sc.parallelize([Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80), Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80), Row(name='Alice', age=10, height=80)]).toDF()
    return df

def test1():
    trA = MyTransformer()
    trA.dataset_count = 999
    print trA.dataset_count
    trA.save('test.trans')
    trB = MyTransformer.load('test.trans')
    print trB.dataset_count

def test2():
    trA = MyTransformer()
    pipeA = Pipeline(stages=[trA])
    print type(pipeA)
    pipeA.save('testA.pipe')
    pipeAA = PysparkPipelineWrapper.unwrap(Pipeline.load('testA.pipe'))
    stagesAA = pipeAA.getStages()
    trAA = stagesAA[0]
    print trAA.dataset_count

def test3():
    dfA = make_a_dataframe(sc)
    trA = MyTransformer()
    pipeA = Pipeline(stages=[trA]).fit(dfA)
    print type(pipeA)
    pipeA.save('testB.pipe')
    pipeAA = PysparkPipelineWrapper.unwrap(PipelineModel.load('testB.pipe'))
    stagesAA = pipeAA.stages
    trAA = stagesAA[0]
    print trAA.dataset_count
    dfB = pipeAA.transform(dfA)
    dfB.show()
```

Comment: Ingenious! Thanks for sharing. Hopefully Spark will soon add the ability to save and load custom all-Python MLlib pipeline stages. Many data scientists use Python rather than Scala/Java and it's not practical to refit/retrain the pipeline model in reality.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work using Python 2.7.12 and Spark 2.2.0 (and Zeppelin 0.7.3). `test1()` fails with: `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'MyTransformer'>: it's not found as __builtin__.MyTransformer`

Comment: @snark I am guessing this worked for you with an earlier version?

Comment: I confess I never tried using it until now:). Despite promising signs at https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/30/developing-custom-machine-learning-algorithms-in-pyspark.html it still looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17025 is not ready yet (and I'd have to wait for the appropriate Spark release anyway).

Comment: Nice method ! Does the pipeline loading also work in Scala ?

Comment: @AdrienForbu no.  These techniques are so we can save custom estimators and transforms in Pyspark Pipelines, as this is not really well supported in when working with Pyspark as it is in Scala.  By the same token, these are strictly Pyspark so can't be used in Scala.

Comment: I am using spark 2.1.0 and I am not able to save the pipeline it throws runtime error recursion limit reached. I have increased the limit still the problem persist. Can someone advice on this issue. Also I could save and load the model spark 2.1.2 but it fails in transform operation.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get @dmbaker's ingenious solution to work using Python 2 on Spark 2.2.0; I kept getting pickling errors. After several blind alleys I got a working solution by modifying his (her?) idea to write and read the parameter values as strings into `StopWordsRemover's` stop words directly.

Here's the **base class** you need if you want to save and load your own estimators or transformers:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover
from pyspark.ml.util import Identifiable, MLWritable, JavaMLWriter, MLReadable, JavaMLReader
from pyspark.ml.wrapper import JavaWrapper, JavaParams

class PysparkReaderWriter(Identifiable, MLReadable, MLWritable):
    """
    A base class for custom pyspark Estimators and Models to support saving and loading directly
    or within a Pipeline or PipelineModel.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(PysparkReaderWriter, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def _getPyObjIdPrefix():
        return "_ThisIsReallyA_"

    @classmethod
    def _getPyObjId(cls):
        return PysparkReaderWriter._getPyObjIdPrefix() + cls.__name__

    def getParamsAsListOfStrings(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("PysparkReaderWriter.getParamsAsListOfStrings() not implemented for instance: %r" % self)

    def write(self):
        """Returns an MLWriter instance for this ML instance."""
        return JavaMLWriter(self)

    def _to_java(self):
        # Convert all our parameters to strings:
        paramValuesAsStrings = self.getParamsAsListOfStrings()

        # Append our own type-specific id so PysparkPipelineLoader can detect this algorithm when unwrapping us.
        paramValuesAsStrings.append(self._getPyObjId())

        # Convert the parameter values to a Java array:
        sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
        java_array = JavaWrapper._new_java_array(paramValuesAsStrings, sc._gateway.jvm.java.lang.String)

        # Create a Java (Scala) StopWordsRemover and give it the parameters as its stop words.
        _java_obj = JavaParams._new_java_obj("org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover", self.uid)
        _java_obj.setStopWords(java_array)
        return _java_obj

    @classmethod
    def _from_java(cls, java_obj):
        # Get the stop words, ignoring the id at the end:
        stopWords = java_obj.getStopWords()[:-1]
        return cls.createAndInitialisePyObj(stopWords)

    @classmethod
    def createAndInitialisePyObj(cls, paramsAsListOfStrings):
        raise NotImplementedError("PysparkReaderWriter.createAndInitialisePyObj() not implemented for type: %r" % cls)

    @classmethod
    def read(cls):
        """Returns an MLReader instance for our clarrier class."""
        return JavaMLReader(StopWordsRemover)

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, path):
        """Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of `read().load(path)`."""
        swr_java_obj = cls.read().load(path)
        return cls._from_java(swr_java_obj)
```

Your own pyspark algorithm must then inherit from `PysparkReaderWriter` and override the `getParamsAsListOfStrings()` method which saves your parameters to a list of strings. Your algorithm must also override the `createAndInitialisePyObj()` method for converting a list of strings back into your parameters. Behind the scenes the parameters are converted to and from the stop words used by `StopWordsRemover`.

**Example estimator** with 3 parameters of different type:

```
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import Param, Params, TypeConverters
from pyspark.ml.base import Estimator

class MyEstimator(Estimator, PysparkReaderWriter):

def __init__(self):
    super(MyEstimator, self).__init__()

# 3 sample parameters, deliberately of different types:
stringParam = Param(Params._dummy(), "stringParam", "A dummy string parameter", typeConverter=TypeConverters.toString)

def setStringParam(self, value):
    return self._set(stringParam=value)

def getStringParam(self):
    return self.getOrDefault(self.stringParam)

listOfStringsParam = Param(Params._dummy(), "listOfStringsParam", "A dummy list of strings.", typeConverter=TypeConverters.toListString)

def setListOfStringsParam(self, value):
    return self._set(listOfStringsParam=value)

def getListOfStringsParam(self):
    return self.getOrDefault(self.listOfStringsParam)

intParam = Param(Params._dummy(), "intParam", "A dummy int parameter.", typeConverter=TypeConverters.toInt)

def setIntParam(self, value):
    return self._set(intParam=value)

def getIntParam(self):
    return self.getOrDefault(self.intParam)

def _fit(self, dataset):
    model = MyModel()
    # Just some changes to verify we can modify the model (and also it's something we can expect to see when restoring it later):
    model.setAnotherStringParam(self.getStringParam() + " World!")
    model.setAnotherListOfStringsParam(self.getListOfStringsParam() + ["E", "F"])
    model.setAnotherIntParam(self.getIntParam() + 10)
    return model

def getParamsAsListOfStrings(self):
    paramValuesAsStrings = []
    paramValuesAsStrings.append(self.getStringParam()) # Parameter is already a string
    paramValuesAsStrings.append(','.join(self.getListOfStringsParam())) # ...convert from a list of strings
    paramValuesAsStrings.append(str(self.getIntParam())) # ...convert from an int
    return paramValuesAsStrings

@classmethod
def createAndInitialisePyObj(cls, paramsAsListOfStrings):
    # Convert back into our parameters. Make sure you do this in the same order you saved them!
    py_obj = cls()
    py_obj.setStringParam(paramsAsListOfStrings[0])
    py_obj.setListOfStringsParam(paramsAsListOfStrings[1].split(","))
    py_obj.setIntParam(int(paramsAsListOfStrings[2]))
    return py_obj
```

**Example Model** (also a Transformer) which has 3 different parameters:

```
from pyspark.ml.base import Model

class MyModel(Model, PysparkReaderWriter):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

    # 3 sample parameters, deliberately of different types:
    anotherStringParam = Param(Params._dummy(), "anotherStringParam", "A dummy string parameter", typeConverter=TypeConverters.toString)

    def setAnotherStringParam(self, value):
        return self._set(anotherStringParam=value)

    def getAnotherStringParam(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.anotherStringParam)

    anotherListOfStringsParam = Param(Params._dummy(), "anotherListOfStringsParam", "A dummy list of strings.", typeConverter=TypeConverters.toListString)

    def setAnotherListOfStringsParam(self, value):
        return self._set(anotherListOfStringsParam=value)

    def getAnotherListOfStringsParam(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.anotherListOfStringsParam)

    anotherIntParam = Param(Params._dummy(), "anotherIntParam", "A dummy int parameter.", typeConverter=TypeConverters.toInt)

    def setAnotherIntParam(self, value):
        return self._set(anotherIntParam=value)

    def getAnotherIntParam(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.anotherIntParam)

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        # Dummy transform code:
        return dataset.withColumn('age2', dataset.age + self.getAnotherIntParam())

    def getParamsAsListOfStrings(self):
        paramValuesAsStrings = []
        paramValuesAsStrings.append(self.getAnotherStringParam()) # Parameter is already a string
        paramValuesAsStrings.append(','.join(self.getAnotherListOfStringsParam())) # ...convert from a list of strings
        paramValuesAsStrings.append(str(self.getAnotherIntParam())) # ...convert from an int
        return paramValuesAsStrings

    @classmethod
    def createAndInitialisePyObj(cls, paramsAsListOfStrings):
        # Convert back into our parameters. Make sure you do this in the same order you saved them!
        py_obj = cls()
        py_obj.setAnotherStringParam(paramsAsListOfStrings[0])
        py_obj.setAnotherListOfStringsParam(paramsAsListOfStrings[1].split(","))
        py_obj.setAnotherIntParam(int(paramsAsListOfStrings[2]))
        return py_obj
```

Below is a sample test case showing how you can save and load your model. It's similar for the estimator so I omit that for brevity.

```
def createAModel():
    m = MyModel()
    m.setAnotherStringParam("Boo!")
    m.setAnotherListOfStringsParam(["P", "Q", "R"])
    m.setAnotherIntParam(77)
    return m

def testSaveLoadModel():
    modA = createAModel()
    print(modA.explainParams())

    savePath = "/whatever/path/you/want"
    #modA.save(savePath) # Can't overwrite, so...
    modA.write().overwrite().save(savePath)

    modB = MyModel.load(savePath)
    print(modB.explainParams())

testSaveLoadModel()
```

Output:

```
anotherIntParam: A dummy int parameter. (current: 77)
anotherListOfStringsParam: A dummy list of strings. (current: ['P', 'Q', 'R'])
anotherStringParam: A dummy string parameter (current: Boo!)
anotherIntParam: A dummy int parameter. (current: 77)
anotherListOfStringsParam: A dummy list of strings. (current: [u'P', u'Q', u'R'])
anotherStringParam: A dummy string parameter (current: Boo!)
```

Notice how the parameters have come back in as unicode strings. This may or may not make a difference to your underlying algorithm that you implement in `_transform()` (or `_fit()` for the estimator). So be aware of this.

Finally, because the Scala algorithm behind the scenes is really a `StopWordsRemover`, you need to unwrap it back into your own class when loading the `Pipeline` or `PipelineModel` from disk. Here's the **utility class** that does this unwrapping:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover

class PysparkPipelineLoader(object):
    """
    A class to facilitate converting the stages of a Pipeline or PipelineModel
    that were saved from PysparkReaderWriter.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(PysparkPipelineLoader, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def unwrap(thingToUnwrap, customClassList):
        if not (isinstance(thingToUnwrap, Pipeline) or isinstance(thingToUnwrap, PipelineModel)):
            raise TypeError("Cannot recognize an object of type %s." % type(thingToUnwrap))

        stages = thingToUnwrap.getStages() if isinstance(thingToUnwrap, Pipeline) else thingToUnwrap.stages
        for i, stage in enumerate(stages):
            if (isinstance(stage, Pipeline) or isinstance(stage, PipelineModel)):
                stages[i] = PysparkPipelineLoader.unwrap(stage)

            if isinstance(stage, StopWordsRemover) and stage.getStopWords()[-1].startswith(PysparkReaderWriter._getPyObjIdPrefix()):

                lastWord = stage.getStopWords()[-1] 
                className = lastWord[len(PysparkReaderWriter._getPyObjIdPrefix()):]

                stopWords = stage.getStopWords()[:-1] # Strip the id

                # Create and initialise the appropriate class:
                py_obj = None
                for clazz in customClassList:
                    if clazz.__name__ == className:
                        py_obj = clazz.createAndInitialisePyObj(stopWords)

                if py_obj is None:
                    raise TypeError("I don't know how to create an instance of type: %s" % className)

                stages[i] = py_obj

        if isinstance(thingToUnwrap, Pipeline):
            thingToUnwrap.setStages(stages)
        else:
            # PipelineModel
            thingToUnwrap.stages = stages
        return thingToUnwrap
```

Test for saving and loading a pipeline:

```
def testSaveAndLoadUnfittedPipeline():
    estA = createAnEstimator()
    #print(estA.explainParams())
    pipelineA = Pipeline(stages=[estA])
    savePath = "/whatever/path/you/want"
    #pipelineA.save(savePath) # Can't overwrite, so...
    pipelineA.write().overwrite().save(savePath)

    pipelineReloaded = PysparkPipelineLoader.unwrap(Pipeline.load(savePath), [MyEstimator])
    estB = pipelineReloaded.getStages()[0]
    print(estB.explainParams())

testSaveAndLoadUnfittedPipeline()
```

Output:

```
intParam: A dummy int parameter. (current: 42)
listOfStringsParam: A dummy list of strings. (current: [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'])
stringParam: A dummy string parameter (current: Hello)
```

Test for saving and loading a pipeline model:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def make_a_dataframe(sc):
    df = sc.parallelize([Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80), Row(name='Bob', age=7, height=85), Row(name='Chris', age=10, height=90)]).toDF()
    return df

def testSaveAndLoadPipelineModel():
    dfA = make_a_dataframe(sc)
    estA = createAnEstimator()
    #print(estA.explainParams())
    pipelineModelA = Pipeline(stages=[estA]).fit(dfA)
    savePath = "/whatever/path/you/want"
    #pipelineModelA.save(savePath) # Can't overwrite, so...
    pipelineModelA.write().overwrite().save(savePath)

    pipelineModelReloaded = PysparkPipelineLoader.unwrap(PipelineModel.load(savePath), [MyModel])
    modB = pipelineModelReloaded.stages[0]
    print(modB.explainParams())

    dfB = pipelineModelReloaded.transform(dfA)
    dfB.show()

testSaveAndLoadPipelineModel()
```

Output:

```
anotherIntParam: A dummy int parameter. (current: 52)
anotherListOfStringsParam: A dummy list of strings. (current: [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E', u'F'])
anotherStringParam: A dummy string parameter (current: Hello World!)
+---+------+-----+----+
|age|height| name|age2|
+---+------+-----+----+
|  5|    80|Alice|  57|
|  7|    85|  Bob|  59|
| 10|    90|Chris|  62|
+---+------+-----+----+
```

When unwrapping a pipeline or pipeline model you have to pass in a list of the classes that correspond to your own pyspark algorithms that are masquerading as `StopWordsRemover` objects in the saved pipeline or pipeline model. The last stop word in your saved object is used to identify your own class's name and then `createAndInitialisePyObj()` is called to create an instance of your class and initialise its parameters with the remaining stop words.

Various refinements could be made. But hopefully this will enable you to save and load custom estimators and transformers, both inside and outside pipelines, until [SPARK-17025](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17025) is resolved and available to you.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44377489/208339) by @dmbaker, I wrapped my custom transformer called `Aggregator` inside of a built-in Spark transformer, in this example, `Binarizer`, though I'm sure you can inherit from other transformers, too. That allowed my custom transformer to inherit the methods necessary for serialization.

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, Binarizer
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression    

class Aggregator(Binarizer):
    """A huge hack to allow serialization of custom transformer."""

    def transform(self, input_df):
        agg_df = input_df\
            .groupBy('channel_id')\
            .agg({
                'foo': 'avg',
                'bar': 'avg',
            })\
            .withColumnRenamed('avg(foo)', 'avg_foo')\
            .withColumnRenamed('avg(bar)', 'avg_bar') 
        return agg_df

# Create pipeline stages.
aggregator = Aggregator()
vector_assembler = VectorAssembler(...)
linear_regression = LinearRegression()

# Create pipeline.
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[aggregator, vector_assembler, linear_regression])

# Train.
pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(input_df)

# Save model file to S3.
pipeline_model.save('s3n://example')
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I'm guessing this shortcut won't work if your custom algorithm has one or more parameters that aren't in the algorithm you're inheriting from...

Comment: I tried your method, and even though the save operation works, when I read my model from and use `transform`, I get an error. Did you ever run into that issue?

Comment: I forget. Honestly, we ended up going with scikit-learn. Spark ML has so much overhead that it wasn't worth it, and you can do tricks to make "big data" fit in scikit-learn which has less overhead, faster prediction and startup, and serializes into one file.

Answer (score 2):

The @dmbaker solution didn't work for me. I believe that is because the python version (2.x versus 3.x). I made some updates on his solution and now it works on Python 3. My setup is listed below:

- python: 3.6.3
- spark: 2.2.1
- dill: 0.2.7.1

```py
class PysparkObjId(object):
   """
   A class to specify constants used to idenify and setup python
   Estimators, Transformers and Models so they can be serialized on there
   own and from within a Pipline or PipelineModel.
   """
        def __init__(self):
            super(PysparkObjId, self).__init__()

        @staticmethod
        def _getPyObjId():
            return '4c1740b00d3c4ff6806a1402321572cb'

        @staticmethod
        def _getCarrierClass(javaName=False):
            return 'org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover' if javaName else StopWordsRemover


    class PysparkPipelineWrapper(object):
        """
        A class to facilitate converting the stages of a Pipeline or PipelineModel
        that were saved from PysparkReaderWriter.
        """
        def __init__(self):
            super(PysparkPipelineWrapper, self).__init__()

        @staticmethod
        def unwrap(pipeline):
            if not (isinstance(pipeline, Pipeline) or isinstance(pipeline, PipelineModel)):
                raise TypeError("Cannot recognize a pipeline of type %s." % type(pipeline))

            stages = pipeline.getStages() if isinstance(pipeline, Pipeline) else pipeline.stages
            for i, stage in enumerate(stages):
                if (isinstance(stage, Pipeline) or isinstance(stage, PipelineModel)):
                    stages[i] = PysparkPipelineWrapper.unwrap(stage)
                if isinstance(stage, PysparkObjId._getCarrierClass()) and stage.getStopWords()[-1] == PysparkObjId._getPyObjId():
                    swords = stage.getStopWords()[:-1] # strip the id
                    # convert stop words to int
                    swords = [int(d) for d in swords]
                    # get the byte value of all ints
                    lst = [x.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder='big') for x in
                           swords]  # convert from string integer list to bytes
                    # return the first byte and concatenates all the others
                    dmp = lst[0]
                    for byte_counter in range(1, len(lst)):
                        dmp = dmp + lst[byte_counter]

                    py_obj = dill.loads(dmp)
                    stages[i] = py_obj

            if isinstance(pipeline, Pipeline):
                pipeline.setStages(stages)
            else:
                pipeline.stages = stages
            return pipeline


    class PysparkReaderWriter(object):
        """
        A mixin class so custom pyspark Estimators, Transformers and Models may
        support saving and loading directly or be saved within a Pipline or PipelineModel.
        """
        def __init__(self):
            super(PysparkReaderWriter, self).__init__()

        def write(self):
            """Returns an MLWriter instance for this ML instance."""
            return JavaMLWriter(self)

        @classmethod
        def read(cls):
            """Returns an MLReader instance for our clarrier class."""
            return JavaMLReader(PysparkObjId._getCarrierClass())

        @classmethod
        def load(cls, path):
            """Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of `read().load(path)`."""
            swr_java_obj = cls.read().load(path)
            return cls._from_java(swr_java_obj)

        @classmethod
        def _from_java(cls, java_obj):
            """
            Get the dumby the stopwords that are the characters of the dills dump plus our guid
            and convert, via dill, back to our python instance.
            """
            swords = java_obj.getStopWords()[:-1] # strip the id
            lst = [x.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder='big') for x in swords] # convert from string integer list to bytes
            dmp = lst[0]
            for i in range(1, len(lst)):
                dmp = dmp + lst[i]
            py_obj = dill.loads(dmp)
            return py_obj

        def _to_java(self):
            """
            Convert this instance to a dill dump, then to a list of strings with the unicode integer values of each character.
            Use this list as a set of dumby stopwords and store in a StopWordsRemover instance
            :return: Java object equivalent to this instance.
            """
            dmp = dill.dumps(self)

            pylist = [str(int(d)) for d in dmp] # convert bytes to string integer list
            pylist.append(PysparkObjId._getPyObjId()) # add our id so PysparkPipelineWrapper can id us.
            sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
            java_class = sc._gateway.jvm.java.lang.String
            java_array = sc._gateway.new_array(java_class, len(pylist))
            for i in range(len(pylist)):
                java_array[i] = pylist[i]
            _java_obj = JavaParams._new_java_obj(PysparkObjId._getCarrierClass(javaName=True), self.uid)
            _java_obj.setStopWords(java_array)

            return _java_obj


    class HasFake(Params):
        def __init__(self):
            super(HasFake, self).__init__()
            self.fake = Param(self, "fake", "fake param")

        def getFake(self):
            return self.getOrDefault(self.fake)


    class CleanText(Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, Identifiable, PysparkReaderWriter, MLReadable, MLWritable):
        @keyword_only
        def __init__(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
            super(CleanText, self).__init__()
            kwargs = self._input_kwargs
            self.setParams(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some base classes to make this easier. Basically I abstract all the complication of the code and initialisation into some base classes that expose a much simpler API to build custom ones. This includes taking care of the serialisation/deserialisation problem and saving and loading SparkML objects. Then you can use concentrate in the `__init__` and `transform/fit` functions. You can find a full explanation with examples in [here](https://medium.com/@rragundez/easily-build-custom-sparkml-transformers-and-estimators-16ba70414abe).