# pyspark.ml pipelines: are custom transformers necessary for basic preprocessing tasks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science

Getting started with `pyspark.ml` and the pipelines API, I find myself writing custom transformers for typical preprocessing tasks in order to use them in a pipeline. Examples:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, Transformer


class CustomTransformer(Transformer):
    # lazy workaround - a transformer needs to have these attributes
    _defaultParamMap = dict()
    _paramMap = dict()
    _params = dict()

class ColumnSelector(CustomTransformer):
    """Transformer that selects a subset of columns
    - to be used as pipeline stage"""

    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns


    def _transform(self, data):
        return data.select(self.columns)


class ColumnRenamer(CustomTransformer):
    """Transformer renames one column"""


    def __init__(self, rename):
        self.rename = rename

    def _transform(self, data):
        (colNameBefore, colNameAfter) = self.rename
        return data.withColumnRenamed(colNameBefore, colNameAfter)


class NaDropper(CustomTransformer):
    """
    Drops rows with at least one not-a-number element
    """

    def __init__(self, cols=None):
        self.cols = cols


    def _transform(self, data):
        dataAfterDrop = data.dropna(subset=self.cols) 
        return dataAfterDrop


class ColumnCaster(CustomTransformer):

    def __init__(self, col, toType):
        self.col = col
        self.toType = toType

    def _transform(self, data):
        return data.withColumn(self.col, data[self.col].cast(self.toType))
```

They work, but I was wondering if this is a pattern or antipattern - are such transformers a good way to work with the pipeline API? Was it necessary to implement them, or is equivalent functionality provided somewhere else?

Comment: how do you call the custom transformers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it is primarily opinion based, although it looks unnecessarily verbose and Python `Transformers` don't integrate well with the rest of the `Pipeline` API.

It is also worth pointing out that everything you have here can be easily achieved with `SQLTransformer`. For example:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import SQLTransformer

def column_selector(columns):
    return SQLTransformer(
        statement="SELECT {} FROM __THIS__".format(", ".join(columns))
    )
```

or

```
def na_dropper(columns):
    return SQLTransformer(
        statement="SELECT * FROM __THIS__ WHERE {}".format(
            " AND ".join(["{} IS NOT NULL".format(x) for x in columns])
        )
    )
```

With a little bit of effort you can use SQLAlchemy with Hive dialect to avoid handwritten SQL.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Python Transformers don't integrate well with the rest of the Pipeline API"?

Comment: By default there are not `MLWritable` (although there are [nice hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41399399/9613318)).

Comment: Well, SQL is not the elegant alternative I had hoped for, but good answer nonetheless -> accept.