# Why does spark-ml ALS model returns NaN and negative numbers predictions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Actually I'm trying to use `ALS` from `spark-ml` with implicit ratings.

I noticed that some predictions given by my trained model are `negative` or `NaN`, why is it?

[image: negative value]

Comment: experienced similar issue. possible reason seen in the answer of this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379751/spark-als-predictall-returns-empty

Comment: Can you show us how you created your model ?

Comment: @eliasah https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/633976740100210/2910709872521072/1005124714215883/latest.html

Comment: I'll take a look at it. You are using Spark 2+ ?

Comment: @eliasah Yes, 2.1

Comment: Ok set "nonnegative=True" for ALS ! That should remove negative values.

Comment: I see but is it natural in the algorithm?  And by the way I used the whole dataset don't know why it's returning NaN

Comment: Well you are just setting the nonnegative constraint to compute least squares

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148419/discussion-between-eliasah-and-alberto-bonsanto).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apache Spark provides an option to force **non negative constraints** on ALS.

Thus, to remove these negative values, you'll just need to set :

**Python:**

```
nonnegative=True
```

**Scala:**

```
setNonnegative(true)
```

when creating your `ALS` model, i.e :

```
>>> als = ALS(rank=10, maxIter=5, seed=0, nonnegative=True)
```

**Non-negative matrix factorization** (NMF or NNMF), also called non-negative matrix approximation is a group of algorithms in multivariate analysis and linear algebra where a matrix **V** is factorized into (usually) two matrices **W** and **H**, with *the property that all three matrices have nonnegative elements* [Ref. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization)].

If you want to read more about NMF , I'd recommend reading the following paper :

- [Collaborative Filtering via Ensembles of Matrix
  Factorizations](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/KDD-cup-2007/proceedings/matrix-fact-Wu.pdf)

As for `NaN` values, usually it's due to splitting your dataset which can lead to unseen items or users if one of them isn't present in the training set and for the matter just present in the testing set. This might also happen if you cross validated your training. For the matter, there is a couple of JIRAs that are marked *resolved* for 2.2 :

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14489.
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19345.

The latest will allow you set the cold start strategy to use when creating your model.